# Delete dir and data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I use form which one upload file into folder and info(name, size) into database.So i want to make deleting form which one delete file and data from database.

```
<?php
include '../dbc.php'; 
$tbl_name="image"; // Table name

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

//detect file
$directory  = "../../Upload/"; 
$images = scandir($directory);
$ignore = Array(".", "..");
?>

 <table width="800px" style="background:white;margin:50px auto; font-size:13px;" border="1" cellpadding="3">
          <tr>
          <td colspan="3"><strong>Delete:</strong> </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
          <td width="40%" align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
          <td width="10%" align="center"><strong>Size</strong></td>
          <td width="5%" align="center"><strong>Delete</strong></td>
          </tr>

          <?php
          while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
          ?>
          <tr id='del'>
          <td><?php echo $rows['name']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo number_format($rows['imgSize'], 2) ?> MB</td>
          <td><a name="delete" href="delData1.php?id=<?php echo $rows['imgId']; 
           ?>">Delete</a></td>
          </tr>

          <?php
          }
          ?>

          </table>
          <?php
          mysql_close();
          ?>
```

delData1.php

```
<?php
include '../dbc.php';
$tbl_name="image"; // Table name
// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['id'];

$filename = $_POST['filename'];
$path = $_POST['directory'];
if(file_exists($path."/".$filename)) { 
 unlink($path."/".$filename); //delete file
}

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE imgId='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully deleted
if($result){
    rmdir('$name');
echo "Deleted";
echo "<BR>";
header("Location:Data.php");
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

It's delete data from database, but file stay in folder.

Comment: You have no form element named "directly" where you're declaring it in `$filename = $_POST['filename'];`. Change `$path = $_POST['directory'];` to `$path = $directory;` and it should work.

Comment: Where you have `$path = $_POST['directory'];` in `delData1.php` change it to `$directory  = "../../Upload/";` since it's in your other body of code.

Comment: it's doesn't work, i think that he don't take file name in delData1.php.. i'll try with form

Comment: Try `$filename = $id;` thenm along with `$directory = "../../Upload/";`

Comment: If unlink fails, it generates a warning. It's a good idea to show all warnings in the development environment. Maybe you've an other notion of the path than the operating system. It's very dangerous too. With this script it's possible to delete every single file that the webserver user can delete not only the uploaded files.